# How to Recompile already installed OpenSSH Package using apt -get install method to hide its Version

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

I have already installed the OpenSSH package in my Ubuntu client system using the `apt-get install` method.
Unfortunately, due to the audit point, I need to hide the OpenSSH version details.

Can we recompile it?

If not, please suggests me how can I hide the OpenSSH version.

Comment: Is your question really about programming? You might want to ask at AskUbuntu or SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.  
It is not related to Ubuntu system. We can hide the version of OpenSSH by modifying the version.h at fresh installation.  
And i m interested in knowing that how can hide the version for OpenSSh which is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by changing the version.h file code

```
#define SSH_VERSION     "OpenSSH_6.4"

#define SSH_PORTABLE    "p1"
#define SSH_RELEASE     SSH_VERSION SSH_PORTABLE
```

to

```
#define SSH_VERSION     "OpenSSH"

#define SSH_PORTABLE    ""
#define SSH_RELEASE     SSH_VERSION SSH_PORTABLE
```

and then

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Will hide the version of already installed OpenSSH using apt-get install or yum install.